# Read file when size of folder is too long

Tags: java, file, filesystems

I am trying to read an image on in my code. But to very large size(more than 1 TB) of the folder in which it is present, my code gets stuck when i try to create File object from this image(the thread has been suck for more than 10 mins). Is there any work around this problem?

Code used for reading image -

```
InputStream userImage = new FileInputStream(new File(imagePath));
```

Comment: Did you try using BufferImage eg:BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(Path);

Comment: Yes, i have but still thread is getting stuck.

Comment: How long does it take for a `echo "some text" > huge_folder/new_file` on the command line? And also for `cat huge_folder/some_file`.

Comment: @SubOptimal `echo` is taking like forever to complete.

Comment: Means this is already slow on OS level (because of the number of entries in the directory). Then anything one layer above the OS can't be faster.